# Java String split("|" ) method call not working correctly

Tags: java, string, split

```
public class SplitStr {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        String str1 = "This | is | My | Account | For | Java|";
        String str2 = "This / is / My / Account / For / Java/";
       // String[] arr = str.split("|");

        for(String item : str1.split("|")) {
            System.out.print(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The program is working correctly with String str2 but it is not working with String str1 What are the possible flows in this program?

Comment: What do you mean not working? Show the output in both cases please.

Comment: you are calling it on str, not on str1. personally, I'm surprised this compiles.

Answer (score 53):

`String#split()` expects a regular expression as the first argument and `|` is a control character in regex.

To make regex parser understand that you mean to split by the literal `|`, you need to pass `\|` to the regex parser. But `\` is a control character in Java string literals. So, to make Java compiler understand that you want to pass `\|` to the regex parser, you need to pass `"\\|"` to the `String#split()` method.

Comment: Good explanation with deep detail. +1

Answer (score 23):

Use

```
str1.split("\\|")
```

instead of

```
str1.split("|")
```

You need to escape `|`

Answer (score 10):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) expects a regular expression, and since `|` is a special character in regular expressions, you have to escape it. Try `str.split("\\|")`. Example:

```
>>> Arrays.asList("This | is | My | Account | For | Java|".split("\\|"));
[This ,  is ,  My ,  Account ,  For ,  Java]
```